# how to use the return value in arrow function in node-js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am working in `express and Node-js` and I am working in `MySql` in Node. I want to store the user data in the database but checking whether the user is already present or not. the working is that on the starting of the function it call the `userpresent` function to check that the is present or not. I want to return the `true or false` but I is returning an object and I cannot handle it the code is what I do in this code to use the return value(which must be true or false) in `route function`:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const database = require('../DBconfig');
var mysql = require('mysql');
const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator');
// to make connection with the database
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'root',
  database: 'yourguide',
});
// connection statement is end
//the route function is start
// here I added some express validators
router.post(
  '/signup',
  [
    body('username', 'enter username of min 4 character').isLength({ min: 3 }),
    body('firstName', 'enter firstName of min 3 character').isLength({
      min: 3,
    }),
    body('lastName', 'enter lastname of min 3 character').isLength({ min: 3 }),
    body('password', 'enter password of min 4 character').isLength({ min: 4 }),
    body('city', 'enter city of min 4 character').isLength({ min: 4 }),
    body('email', 'entera valid email').isEmail(),
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    const error = validationResult(req);
    //check that the user enter a valid input
    var flag = await userPresent(req.body.username, req.body.email);
    if (!error.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: error.array() });
    } else {
      // if the input is valid then start to check the user
      await connection.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) console.log('not conntected to table');
        else console.log('connected to table');
        // call the async function to check the presence of the user
        console.log('flag in main is ');
        console.log(flag);
        //check the return value of the fucntion
        //if the user is not present then execute the if statement
        if (!flag) {
          //make the query
          var query = `INSERT INTO users(firstName, lastName, username, email, city, password) VALUES ("${req.body.firstName}","${req.body.lastName}","${req.body.username}","${req.body.email}","${req.body.city}","${req.body.password}")`;
          console.log(query);
          connection.query(query, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
              flag = false;
              console.log('not inserted');
              return flag;
            } else {
              flag = true;
              console.log('inserted');
              return flag;
            }
          });
          return res.body;
        } else {
          return res
            .status(400)
            .json({ error: 'given email or username is already exist' });
        }
      });
    }
  }
);

//async function to check the user presence
userPresent = async (username, email) => {
  //initialize the flag with true

  let data = '';
  //make query to check the user
  var query = `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username= "${username}" AND email="${email}" `;
  data = await connection.query(
    query,
    (present = (err, result) => {
      return result != null;
    })
  );
  console.log('data is ', data);
};
```

the `userpresent` function return the object

```
_events: [Object: null prototype] {
    error: [Function (anonymous)],
    packet: [Function (anonymous)],
    timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
    end: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  _eventsCount: 4,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _callback: [Function (anonymous)],
  _callSite: Error
      at Protocol._enqueue (D:\practise\yourguide\yourguide\backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
      at Connection.query (D:\practise\yourguide\yourguide\backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:198:25)
      at userPresent (D:\practise\yourguide\yourguide\backend\routes\user.js:83:29)
      at D:\practise\yourguide\yourguide\backend\routes\user.js:28:22
      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\practise\yourguide\yourguide\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
      at next (D:\practise\yourguide\yourguide\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
      at middleware (D:\practise\yourguide\yourguide\backend\node_modules\express-validator\src\middlewares\check.js:16:13)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5),
  _ended: false,
  _timeout: undefined,
  _timer: Timer { _object: [Circular *1], _timeout: null },
  sql: 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username= "harry13" AND email="harry13@gmail.com" ',
  values: undefined,
  typeCast: true,
  nestTables: false,
  _resultSet: null,
  _results: [],
  _fields: [],
  _index: 0,
  _loadError: null,
  _connection: <ref *2> Connection {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    config: ConnectionConfig {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3306,
      localAddress: undefined,
      socketPath: undefined,
      user: 'root',
      password: 'root',
      database: 'yourguide',
      connectTimeout: 10000,
      insecureAuth: false,
      supportBigNumbers: false,
      bigNumberStrings: false,
      dateStrings: false,
      debug: undefined,
      trace: true,
      stringifyObjects: false,
      timezone: 'local',
      flags: '',
      queryFormat: undefined,
      pool: undefined,
      ssl: false,
      localInfile: true,
      multipleStatements: false,
      typeCast: true,
      maxPacketSize: 0,
      charsetNumber: 33,
      clientFlags: 455631
    },
    _socket: Socket {
      connecting: true,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'localhost',
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 5,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: null,
      _server: null,
      timeout: 10000,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 36,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TCP],
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: Timeout {
        _idleTimeout: 10000,
        _idlePrev: [TimersList],
        _idleNext: [TimersList],
        _idleStart: 3579,
        _onTimeout: [Function: bound ],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: null,
        _destroyed: false,
        [Symbol(refed)]: false,
        [Symbol(kHasPrimitive)]: false,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 39,
        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 0
      },
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0
    },
    _protocol: Protocol {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      readable: true,
      writable: true,
      _config: [ConnectionConfig],
      _connection: [Circular *2],
      _callback: null,
      _fatalError: null,
      _quitSequence: null,
      _handshake: true,
      _handshaked: false,
      _ended: false,
      _destroyed: false,
      _queue: [Array],
      _handshakeInitializationPacket: null,
      _parser: [Parser],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    _connectCalled: true,
    state: 'disconnected',
    threadId: null,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
}
```

what I do to return the true or false to use in our `route function`

Comment: You need to learn how to actually use `await` with your database.  Hint, `await` only does something useful when you are awaiting a promise and your database does NOT return a promise unless you use a database interface module (like `mysql2/promise`) that supports promises and then don't pass a callback at all - you just use the promise.

Comment: On top of all that, your use of the `userPresent()` function followed by an insert if it doesn't yet exist is a race condition.  The user present state can change between the time you check it and then try to insert it.  You need to do the check and insert with a single database operation.  I don't know your DB interface, but more typically, you would set up your table to not allow duplicates on the userID key and then just do the insert.  If it succeeds, then you've now added it, if it doesn't succeed, then it was already there - no race condition.